# Curl multiple for loops

Tags: bash, shell, curl, git-bash

I'm unsuccessfully trying to run a couple of "for loops" with a curl POST call.

There are multiple entity IDs, each with a different version.
In order to successfully change the status of each of these entities, I would have to match them up with their version. Seeing as I know the entity IDs and I'm able to get a list of version IDs, doing two "for loops" seems the most approachable idea for my "skill"set.

```
for i in {12345,12346}; do for j in $(seq 0 3); do curl -b cookies.txt https://mydomain(dot)com/${i} -d 'status=0&version=${j}';done done;
```

I get a "version conflict" error - meaning that the J value wasn't replaced

If I try

```
for i in {12345,12346}; do for j in $(seq 0 3); do echo curl -b cookies.txt "https://mydomain(dot)com/${i} -d 'status=0&version=${j}'";done done;
```

I get the following response, which means no actual changes have been made to the status of the entities

```
curl -b cookies.txt https://mydomain(dot)com/12345 -d 'status=0&version=0'
curl -b cookies.txt https://mydomain(dot)com/12345 -d 'status=0&version=1'
curl -b cookies.txt https://mydomain(dot)com/12345 -d 'status=0&version=2'
curl -b cookies.txt https://mydomain(dot)com/12345 -d 'status=0&version=3'
curl -b cookies.txt https://mydomain(dot)com/12346 -d 'status=0&version=0'
curl -b cookies.txt https://mydomain(dot)com/12346 -d 'status=0&version=1'
curl -b cookies.txt https://mydomain(dot)com/12346 -d 'status=0&version=2'
curl -b cookies.txt https://mydomain(dot)com/12346 -d 'status=0&version=3'
```

Ideally there would be only two POSTs made by the call, one for each entity ID with its corresponding version.
However, based on the structure I created, I would expect that out of 8 POSTs, six would fail because of a "version conflict" and two would be successful as the versions of the two entities would be in the j list.

Any help/pointers would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first version you are using single quotes and therefore the string interpolation does not work. In your second example you are using double quotes. Try changing them to double quotes in the first example as well.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like the double quotes worked out as I expected - 8 calls, 6 failed because of version conflict and 2 where successful `for i in {12345,12346}; do for j in $(seq 0 3); do curl -b cookies.txt https://mydomain(dot)com/${i} -d "status=0&version=${j}";done done;`